# Vectorize for loop and return x day high and low

Tags: pandas

**Overview**

For each row of a dataframe I want to calculate the  x day high and low.

An x day high is higher than previous x days.
An x day low is lower than previous x days.

The for loop is explained in further detail in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138987/pandas-calculate-x-day-high-value)

**Update**:

Answer by @mozway below completes in around 20 seconds with dataset containing 18k rows.  Can this be improved with numpy with broadcasting etc?

**Example**

`2020-03-20`  has an `x_day_low` value of `1` as it is lower than the previous day.

`2020-03-27` has an `x_day_high` value of `8` as it is higher than the previous 8 days.

See desired output and test code below which is calculated with a for loop in the `findHighLow` function.  How would I vectorize `findHighLow` as the actual dataframe is somewhat larger.

**Test data**

```
def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 
   
    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    fxDF.columns = [i.title() for i in fxDF.columns]
    return fxDF

#rows set to 15 for minimal example but actual dataframe contains around 18000 rows.
number_of_rows = 15    

df = genMockDataFrame(number_of_rows,1.1904,'tttmmm','19/3/2020',seed=157)

def findHighLow (df):

    df['x_day_high'] = 0
    df['x_day_low'] = 0

    for n in reversed(range(len(df['High']))):
        for i in reversed(range(n)):
                if df['High'][n] > df['High'][i]:
                    df['x_day_high'][n] = n - i
                else: break

    for n in reversed(range(len(df['Low']))):
        for i in reversed(range(n)):
                if df['Low'][n] < df['Low'][i]:
                    df['x_day_low'][n] = n - i
                else: break
    return df

df = findHighLow (df)
```

**Desired output should match this:**

```
df[["High","Low","x_day_high","x_day_low"]]

             High   Low x_day_high  x_day_low
date                
2020-03-19  1.1937  1.1832  0       0
2020-03-20  1.1879  1.1769  0       1
2020-03-21  1.1767  1.1662  0       2
2020-03-22  1.1721  1.1611  0       3
2020-03-23  1.1819  1.1690  2       0
2020-03-24  1.1928  1.1807  4       0
2020-03-25  1.1939  1.1864  6       0
2020-03-26  1.2141  1.1964  7       0
2020-03-27  1.2144  1.2039  8       0
2020-03-28  1.2099  1.2018  0       1
2020-03-29  1.2033  1.1853  0       4
2020-03-30  1.1887  1.1806  0       6
2020-03-31  1.1972  1.1873  1       0 
2020-04-01  1.1997  1.1914  2       0
2020-04-02  1.1924  1.1781  0       9
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: Question updated with explanation

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138987/pandas-calculate-x-day-high-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two so solutions. Both produce the desired output, as posted in the question.

The first solution uses Numba and completes in 0.5 seconds on my machine for 20k rows. If you can use Numba, this is the way to go. The second solution uses only Pandas/Numpy and completes in 1.5 seconds for 20k rows.

### Numba

```py
@numba.njit
def count_smaller(arr):
    current = arr[-1]
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]-2, -1, -1):
        if arr[i] > current:
            break
        
        count += 1
        
    return count


@numba.njit
def count_greater(arr):
    current = arr[-1]
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]-2, -1, -1):
        if arr[i] < current:
            break
        
        count += 1
        
    return count

df["x_day_high"] = df.High.expanding().apply(count_smaller, engine='numba', raw=True)
df["x_day_low"] = df.Low.expanding().apply(count_greater, engine='numba', raw=True)
```

### Pandas/Numpy

```py
def count_consecutive_true(bool_arr):
    return bool_arr[::-1].cumprod().sum()

def count_smaller(arr):
    return count_consecutive_true(arr <= arr[-1]) - 1

def count_greater(arr):
    return count_consecutive_true(arr >= arr[-1]) - 1

df["x_day_high"] = df.High.expanding().apply(count_smaller, raw=True)
df["x_day_low"] = df.Low.expanding().apply(count_greater, raw=True)
```

This last solution is similar to mozway's. However it runs faster because it doesn't need to perform a join and uses numpy as much as possible. It also looks arbitrarily far back.

Comment: Note: I have updated the Pandas/Numpy solution to use `raw=True` which speeds it up by 3x.

Comment: is it possible to break it down and explain how the Pandas/Numpy solution is working please?  many thanks

Comment: I understand most of this but not the `-1` at the end of `count_consecutive_true(arr <= arr[-1]) - 1`.

Comment: `count_consecutive_true` returns the number of  consecutive array elements where the condition is true (counted from the end of the array). There will always be at least one element where `arr <= arr[-1]`, namely the last one `arr[-1]`. Hence the minimal value of `count_consecutive_true(arr <= arr[-1])` is `1` and we need to subtract it. 
Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rolling` to get the last N days, a comparison + `cumprod` on the reversed boolean array to keep only the last consecutive valid values, and `sum` to count them. Apply on each column using `agg` and `join` the output after adding a prefix.

```
# number of days
N = 8

df.join(df.rolling(f'{N+1}d', min_periods=1)
          .agg({'High': lambda s: s.le(s.iloc[-1])[::-1].cumprod().sum()-1,
                'Low': lambda s: s.ge(s.iloc[-1])[::-1].cumprod().sum()-1,
               })
          .add_prefix(f'{N}_days_')
        )
```

Output:

```
              Open    High     Low   Close  8_days_High  8_days_Low
date                                                               
2020-03-19  1.1904  1.1937  1.1832  1.1832          0.0         0.0
2020-03-20  1.1843  1.1879  1.1769  1.1772          0.0         1.0
2020-03-21  1.1755  1.1767  1.1662  1.1672          0.0         2.0
2020-03-22  1.1686  1.1721  1.1611  1.1721          0.0         3.0
2020-03-23  1.1732  1.1819  1.1690  1.1819          2.0         0.0
2020-03-24  1.1836  1.1928  1.1807  1.1922          4.0         0.0
2020-03-25  1.1939  1.1939  1.1864  1.1936          6.0         0.0
2020-03-26  1.1967  1.2141  1.1964  1.2114          7.0         0.0
2020-03-27  1.2118  1.2144  1.2039  1.2089          7.0         0.0
2020-03-28  1.2080  1.2099  1.2018  1.2041          0.0         1.0
2020-03-29  1.2033  1.2033  1.1853  1.1880          0.0         4.0
2020-03-30  1.1876  1.1887  1.1806  1.1879          0.0         6.0
2020-03-31  1.1921  1.1972  1.1873  1.1939          1.0         0.0
2020-04-01  1.1932  1.1997  1.1914  1.1914          2.0         0.0
2020-04-02  1.1902  1.1924  1.1781  1.1862          0.0         7.0
```

Comment: I marked your answer as useful and this is faster than the existing code.  It is still very slow if setting `n=500` and a dataframe with thousands of rows.  I'm also interested in i.e. 1000 days highs/lows and running on large datasets.

Comment: I an not sure you can do much better with pandas. Limitations are the rolling with timestamps, which you can avoid of you're sure there are all consecutive days. If you have a lot of RAM, you could use numpy with broadcasting. Maybe provide more info on your dataset, available computing power, current and expected running time.